# How replace string with regex in bash script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, date, glob

I have this working in terminal (it just remove the date using string replacement)

```bash
NAME="/home/me/a_path/2023-04-10 filename"
NEW_NAME=$(echo ${NAME//20[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9] /})
echo ${NEW_NAME}
>>> Expected output :  "/home/me/a_path/filename"
```

But this is not working (it output the non-modified string) in script, I can't understand why.

I tried different quotation marks positions and some other things that I found on SO, but nothing has worked for me yet.
I tried using sed it does not work better.

Edit: The example I gave is working, so probably a typo in my full script

Comment: please update the question with your script (that's not working) and an explanation of what you mean by *`not working`* ... does it generate an error? does it generate the wrong result? does it do nothing? does it hang? something else?

Comment: in this case there's no need for the sub-process call to `echo`; a more efficient equivalent: `NEW_NAME="${NAME//20[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9] /}"`

Comment: Edit done. Thanks for that, doesn't solve the problem tho.

Comment: we still need to see your *actual* script ... the one that's not working; there's no way `echo NEW_NAME` is generating any sort of output other than the literal string `NEW_NAME`; we also need to see how you are calling the script

Comment: If your script is a bash script (read: uses a bash shebang), then paste the contents into https://www.shellcheck.net/  and make any recommended changes.

Comment: if I take the exact code you've provided, change the last line to `echo "${NEW_NAME}"`, put it in a script with a `bash` shebang call it from the command line ... it generates the desired output; my guesses ... there's a typo in the actual script ... or you're not running this under `bash`

Comment: I solve my problem but to be honest I don't know how. Probably a typo :/ mb mb. I didn't what shebang was. Thanks y'all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is another approach without regex based on the inputs provided in the asked question.

```
#!/bin/bash

NAME="/home/me/a_path/2023-04-10 filename"
DIR=$(dirname "${NAME}")
FILE=$(basename "${NAME}" | awk '{print $NF}')

echo "${DIR}/${FILE}"
```

The output:
`/home/me/a_path/filename`